# React Native Reanimated conditional exiting and entering animations

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm currently using `React Animated View` with `exiting` and `entering` props to make a transition while user clicks on **Continue** or **Return** button inside a screen (there's no route navigation, it stay in the given screen).

Currently, I'm using `entering: SlideInRight` and `exiting: SlideOutLeft`, which produces a navigation next animation, and it works like a charm if user click on **Continue** button.

How can I change the direction of the slide if user click on the **Return** button? (`entering: SlideInLeft` and `exiting: SlideOutRight`)

Code sample of the code structure:

```js
const ScreenComponent = () => {
  
  return (
    <View>
       <HeaderComponent />
       <Animated.View entering={SlideInRight} exiting={SlideOutLeft}>
         <ConditionalComponent /> // it changes when user clicks Continue or Return
       </Animated.View>
       <FooterComponent
         onContinue={callNextConditionalComponent}
         onContinue={callPreviousConditionalComponent} />
    </Animated.View>
  )
}
```

I've tried searching in the Reanimated 2 docs for a solution using the `entering` and `exiting` props, but I haven't found any way to do it conditionally. Using the React Native animation, I saw I could achieve it using the `Animated.timing`, but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: have you tried this workaround? https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3662#issuecomment-1369107481